# Find volume of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2$ contained in $z \geq 0$, $y \leq x$ and $y \geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I am asked the following question:

> Find the volume of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2$ contained in $z \geq 0$, $y \leq x$ and $y \geq 0$

What i gather from the information presented is:

$$
\begin{align*}
z \geq 0 &\Rightarrow 0 \leq \phi \leq \pi/2\\
y \geq 0 \text{ and } y \leq x &\Rightarrow 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/4\\
x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2 &\Rightarrow 0 \leq \rho \leq a
\end{align*}
$$

Ist that correct? Should I evaluate the following?

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a} \rho^2 \sin(\phi) \ d\rho d\phi d\theta
\end{align*}
$$

Thank you.

Comment: you are on the right track.

Comment: $1/8$ of the volume of the ball of radius $a$, for symmetry reasons, isn't enough as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a purely geometric point of view, is it clear that you should be getting one $\;16\,-$ th of the total volume of the sphere?:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a} \rho^2 \sin(\phi) \ d\rho d\phi d\theta=\frac\pi4\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\phi\left.\frac13\rho^3\right|_0^a=$$

$$=\left.\frac{a^3\pi}{12}(-\cos\phi)\right|_0^{\pi/2}=\frac{a^3\pi}{12}=\frac1{16}\cdot\color{red}{\frac43a^3\pi}$$

as expected.